# onClose mui drawer function is executed multiple times on multiple clicks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have mui Drawer + Formik + React

```
<Drawer anchor="right" open={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
```

When we close the drawer `onClose` is executed. We also have `onBackdropClick` and `hideBackdrop` props

When I close the drawer `onClose` runs, if I click multiple times outside of the drawer `onClose` function executes multiple times. This is the solution I wrote:

```
  const formik = useFormik<SomeType>({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema: Schema,
    onSubmit: (values) => onFormSubmit(values), // this function will be executed if we write `formik.handleSubmit()`
  });

  const onClose = async () => {
    const { values, dirty, setSubmitting, isSubmitting } = formik;
    const { recurrenceType } = values;

    if (!dirty) {
      onSidebarClose(); // <=== close the sidebar if we didn't change anything in the form
    }

    if (isSubmitting) return;

    setSubmitting(true);

    if (condition1) {
      await request1(formik);
    } else if (condition2) {
      await request2(values);
    } else if (condition3) {
      await request3(values);
    }

    setSubmitting(false);
  };
```

In this case, the user won't be able to send multiple requests at once.

This solution is not clear, maybe someone knows a better solution?

**Problem**: run onClose function only once to prevent multiple requests from being made at once

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `useEffect` with `[isOpen]` as one of dependencies. You also may need to change the `onClose={onClose}` to simple function than changes `isOpen` value to something like `onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}`.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (!isOpen && (some conditions in order to prevent function execution on component mount)) {
       onClose()
   } 
}, [isOpen, other, dependencies])
```